# error in using pattern.db

Tags: python, database

I use pattern.db module from pattern-2.5 in python to make a database, but when i run it, there is a message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cobadb.py", line 25, in <module>
    db = Database('my_stuff')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pattern/db/__init__.py", line 381, in __init__
    _import_db(type)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pattern/db/__init__.py", line 54, in _import_db
    import pysqlite2.dbapi2 as sqlite
ImportError: No module named pysqlite2.dbapi2
```

Comment: Could you post the output of `python -c 'import sqlite3.dbapi2 as sqlite'`

Answer (score 0):

As is quite clear from the message, you need to install `pysqlite2`.

Comment: The code in Pattern first tries to import `sqlite3`, which should exist in Python 2.7. If that fails, it tries to import (the really ancient) `pysqlite2`. So there's something fishy going on...

Comment: i can't install it..when i install it, there's message that i need gcc.,but actually i have installed gcc..

Comment: @AdhimasYudha that's a different problem. Installing that from source when it could be available in your distribution is another problem. Not being able to use sqlite3 is yet another one.